# jsf - facelets - pack library jar with *.xhtml-s and beans only

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, taglib, composite-component

I could read the [tutorial](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/create-common-facelets-jar) which describes how to pack **facelets** to jar to reuse tags as library...

The thing is the instruction recommends using both JSP and JSF in manner as (*see code snippet*);

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" version="2.0">

    <ui:composition>
        ...
    </ui:composition>
</jsp:root>
```

...and using both ***.taglib.xml*** + **.tld** conf files... :(

So I don't get it may `ui:composition` in *.xhtml be started as usual by (*see code snippet*) ...

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" version="2.0">

   ...
</ui:composition>
```

...not to deal with jsp at all? And if, yes, how this kind of library can be added to **dynamic web project** in eclipse for example?

So my question concerning the tutorial is...

**A)** is there a way to avoid using *.tld and use have *.taglib.xml only for the lib if the tag library will contain xhtml files only?

**B)** is there a way to  have xhtml-s in non META-INF sub-folder but in some random one?

**C)** How to automate this kind of library creation process? I mean should I create a project in eclipse (?project category) to have correct folders structure by default to make possible re-compile it and test it and only after that pack it as a jsf library?

I googled a lot but couldn't find solutions variations so please share your experience;

Thanks

Comment: In stackoverflow it is good practice to ask 1 question per question.

Comment: @Kukeltje the question is about the tutorial adaptation; The tutorial makes me really confused why that guy uses jsp saying "Create a Common Facelets Tag Library" :S Can it be done a pure JSF way?

Comment: It is an almost 10 year old article... Ignore it... Search for newer ones!!!

Comment: @Kukeltje I'd love to but seems like there is no newer ones concerning how to create jsf facelets tag lib :P Maybe you can advise some? Most newer tutorials show how to deal with components libs not the facelets libs...